# EBUSY on Gatsby

Tags: windows, gatsby

When running 'gatsby develop' or 'gatsby build' this error is returned, causing the build to fail.

```
ordpress/05131cb1d9a46f72f621b56852b5ab9a/rs-hero.png to C:\__PATH__\public\static\d7c151e623bf472c2f10e2ce051fe8d8\rs-hero.png [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked,
copyfile 'C:\__PATH__\.cache\caches\gatsby-source-wordpress\05131
cb1d9a46f72f621b56852b5ab9a\rs-hero.png' -> 'C:\__PATH__\public\s
tatic\d7c151e623bf472c2f10e2ce051fe8d8\rs-hero.png'] {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: 'C:\\__PATH__\\.cache\\caches\\gatsby-source-wordpress\\05131cb1d9a46f72f621b56852b5ab9a\\rs-hero.png',
  dest: 'C:\\__PATH__\\public\\static\\d7c151e623bf472c2f10e2ce
051fe8d8\\rs-hero.png'
}
```

Here's my gatsby info:

```
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.15 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.10 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1266.0), Chromium (95.0.1020.30)
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.0.1 => 4.0.1
    gatsby-background-image: ^1.5.3 => 1.5.3
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^2.0.0 => 2.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-nprogress: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-svg: ^3.0.1 => 3.1.0
    gatsby-plugin-remove-fingerprints: ^0.0.2 => 0.0.2
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^5.0.0 => 5.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^4.0.1 => 4.0.1
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^4.10.0 => 4.10.0
    gatsby-plugin-styled-components: ^4.14.0 => 4.14.0
    gatsby-plugin-svgr-loader: ^0.1.0 => 0.1.0
    gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader: ^1.0.4 => 1.0.4
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
    gatsby-source-wordpress: ^6.0.0 => 6.0.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^4.0.0 => 4.0.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 4.0.0
```

I've tried clearing npm cache and gatsby cache. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clearing the cache (and keeping the files), try deleting all your `node_modules` and reinstalling them:

1. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `npm cache clean` (may not need this step)